# API Request : TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to do an API request of this in Ruby On Rails :

https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes

I tried this code :

```
class PagesController \< ApplicationController
  def home
    require "uri"
    require "net/http"
    require "json"

    url = "https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes"
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    json = JSON.parse(response)
    puts json["quote"]
  end
end
```

But I have this error in my terminal :

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
>
> app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:13:in []' app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:13:in home'

How can I fix this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The response is an array with one element, so try:

```rb
puts json[0]["quote"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the first line:

```
class PagesController \< ApplicationController

class PagesController < ApplicationController
```

The required statements should be outside a function unless you know what you are doing...

And please share more info so we could understand the way you are trying to access the object.